# Titlesec and titles vertical alignement

Tags: titlesec

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\frenchspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\thechapter}{0pt}{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont\itshape}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Brevissima storia della retorica}
\section{Il mondo antico e medievale}
\subsection{La retorica sofistica}

\end{document}
```

I obtain a bad tabulation of subsection, for it prodrudes from the section title:
[image]

How is it possible to produce a correct vertical alignement? thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `\phantom{\thesection}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\frenchspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\scshape\roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\thechapter}{0pt}{}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont\itshape}{\phantom{\thesection}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Brevissima storia della retorica}
\section{Il mondo antico e medievale}
\subsection{La retorica sofistica}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx! Generally, phantomsection  sets an anchor at this location. But you use  '\phantom '. Which is here its function?